# Pyspark : select specific column with its position

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to know how to select a specific column with its number but not with its name in a dataframe ?

Like this in Pandas:

```
df = df.iloc[:,2]
```

It's possible ?

Comment: You can use `df[i]` to select column `i` of the DataFrame.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can always get the name of the column with `df.columns[n]` and then `select` it:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([[1,2], [3,4]], ['a', 'b'])
```

To select column at position `n`:

```
n = 1
df.select(df.columns[n]).show()
+---+                                                                           
|  b|
+---+
|  2|
|  4|
+---+
```

To select all but column `n`:

```
n = 1
```

You can either use `drop`:

```
df.drop(df.columns[n]).show()
+---+
|  a|
+---+
|  1|
|  3|
+---+
```

Or select with manually constructed column names:

```
df.select(df.columns[:n] + df.columns[n+1:]).show()
+---+
|  a|
+---+
|  1|
|  3|
+---+
```

Comment: ok, thanks you ! Is it possible to select all but one column with this line of code? Select column 1 to 4 and 6 to 10 ?

Comment: You can use `df.drop(df.columns[5])` to drop a column. see the update

Comment: doesn't work for case when there are columns with same name

Answer (score -2):

Same solution as mirkhosro:

For a dataframe df, you can select the column n using `df[n]`, where n is the **index** of the column.

Example:

```
df = df.filter(df[3]!=0)
```

will remove the rows of df, where the value in the fourth column is 0.

Note that you can check the columns using `df.printSchema()`