# Pyspark equivalent of iloc function

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I am converting pandas code to pyspark.

Pandas code:

```py
for k, v in df.items():
    xy = x.iloc[1:, v]
```

Below code is giving error:

```py
for k, v in df.items():
    xy = x.select(*x.columns[v:])
```

This error I'm getting:

> "TypeError: list indices must be integer or slices, not list".

Comment: Are you using Aws databricks or azure databricks or community?

Comment: pyspark does not have indices due to its distributed nature. however, you could try `pandas API on spark`.

Comment: related: [PySpark Data Frames when to use .select()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73347065/12846804)
[Pyspark : select specific column with its position](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50910399/12846804)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assert a value of a specific cell in spark df in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70862644/assert-a-value-of-a-specific-cell-in-spark-df-in-python) The accepted answer: *using collect() is the way (which is equivalent of iloc() in Pandas df)*